# Two notions of singular support?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, singularity-theory, derived-algebraic-geometry, singular-support

Arinkin-Gaitsgory have defined the notion of singular support for any quasismooth $Y$
$$\text{SS}(\mathcal{F})\ \subseteq\ \text{Sing}(Y)$$
and $\mathcal{F}$ any ind-coherent sheaf, where $\text{Sing}(Y)$ is the category of singularities of $Y$ (the classical truncation of the minus one shifted cotangent complex). Thus when $Y$ is a smooth classical scheme, $\text{Sing}(Y)=Y$.

On the other hand, there is a classical notion of singular support of a D module/$\ell$ adic sheaf/constructible sheaf... on any (at least smooth) $Y$
$$\text{SS}(\mathcal{F})\ \subseteq\ T^*Y.$$
See e.g. section 2.2 of [D-Modules, Perverse Sheaves, and Representation Theory](https://personal.math.ubc.ca/%7Ecautis/dmodules/hottaetal.pdf).

What precisely is the relation between these two notions of singular support?

Comment: I'm confused; if $Y$ is smooth, shouldn't $\text{Sing}(Y)$ be empty, rather than equal to all of $Y$?

Comment: @ViditNanda It's the total space of $H^{-1}(\mathbf{T}^*_Y)$, which when $Y$ is smooth is the zero vector bundle, whose total space is just $Y$.

Comment: Let me verify: is the later basically characterizing the ULAness of the constructible sheaf or the regular holonomic D-module along the direction given by the co-vector?

Comment: @Z.M I don't know what ULA is, but I mean the notion in HTT/Kashiwara Schapiro, e.g. the support of the associated graded of the D module, or the "microlocal directions in which the constructible sheaf is not locally constant".

Comment: OK, I was thinking about the relative case (a reference is [[Hansen–Scholze](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2109.06766.pdf),§3]), and when the base is a point, it is essentially being locally constant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When $X$ is a smooth scheme, the derived loop space (i.e. odd tangent bundle) $\mathcal{L}X\simeq\mathbb{T}_X[-1]$ has $\mathrm{Sing}(\mathbb{T}_X[-1]) = T^*X$.  Furthermore, there is a Koszul duality:
$$\mathrm{Coh}(\mathbb{T}_X[-1])^{B\mathbb{G}_a \rtimes \mathbb{G}_m} \simeq F\mathcal{D}(X)$$
where the right-hand side is filtered $\mathcal{D}$-modules.  Forgetting the $B\mathbb{G}_a$-action corresponds to taking the associated graded, and this Koszul duality becomes the linear Koszul duality of [Mirkovic--Riche](https://arxiv.org/abs/0804.0923):
$$\mathrm{Coh}(\mathbb{T}_X[-1])^{\mathbb{G}_m} \simeq \mathrm{Coh}(\mathbb{T}^*_X)^{\mathbb{G}_m}$$
and  the notion of singular support on the left corresponds to the classical support on the right (i.e. singular support of the corresponding $\mathcal{D}$-module).

This was first written up by [Ben-Zvi--Nadler](https://arxiv.org/abs/1002.3636).  I have a follow-up [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2301.06949) for stacks and there are some references in the intro.  I should say that I think none of us write up the compatibility of singular support, but one can use for example the point-wise characterization in [Section 6 of Arinkin--Gaitsgory](https://arxiv.org/abs/1201.6343).